# Compute the mean of the counting of row each 10 minutes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a timestamp column. I'm able to group by the rows of this dataframe by timestamps in the range of 1 minute (or more), as you can see from the code below

```
minutes = '1T'
grouped_df=df.loc[df['id_area'] == 3].groupby(pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]).dt.floor(minutes))["x"].count()
```

When I print the dataframe I get this

```
    timestamp
2022-11-09 14:14:00    3
2022-11-09 14:17:00    2
2022-11-09 14:28:00    1
2022-11-09 15:10:00    1
2022-11-09 15:35:00    1
2022-11-09 16:12:00    1
2022-11-09 16:14:00    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

I need to group by the timestamp by 10 minutes, then I need to count the rows in the then minutes range, and compute the mean.

So for example I have 5 in total as sum in the range of ten minutes between 14:10 and 14:20, I need to divide 5 by the number of rows in this range that is two and save the nearest integer

Expected output

```
timestamp
2022-11-09 14:10:00    3
2022-11-09 14:20:00    1
2022-11-09 15:10:00    1
2022-11-09 15:30:00    1
2022-11-09 16:10:00    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`Resampler.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.mean.html):

```
df1 = grouped_df.resample('10T').mean()
print (df1)
                       x
timestamp               
2022-11-09 14:10:00  2.5
2022-11-09 14:20:00  1.0
2022-11-09 14:30:00  NaN
2022-11-09 14:40:00  NaN
2022-11-09 14:50:00  NaN
2022-11-09 15:00:00  NaN
2022-11-09 15:10:00  1.0
2022-11-09 15:20:00  NaN
2022-11-09 15:30:00  1.0
2022-11-09 15:40:00  NaN
2022-11-09 15:50:00  NaN
2022-11-09 16:00:00  NaN
2022-11-09 16:10:00  1.0
```

Or use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
df2 = grouped_df.groupby(grouped_df.index.floor('10T')).mean()
print (df2)
                       x
timestamp               
2022-11-09 14:10:00  2.5
2022-11-09 14:20:00  1.0
2022-11-09 15:10:00  1.0
2022-11-09 15:30:00  1.0
2022-11-09 16:10:00  1.0
```

Comment: the output can be an integer instead of a float?

Comment: @JayJona - If use `mean`, is possible get floats, because mean is division sum by counts. Are you sure need integers?

Comment: @JayJona - If use `grouped_df.resample('10T').mean().round(0).astype('Int64')`

Comment: I tried it using resample I obtain all the dates between two dates so if I have 11/01 and 11/30 I get lot of useless rows, if I use DatetimeIndex.floor and in this way the mean is computed considering always the number of minutes in the range of 10 minutes so 10. For example I obtain 0.5

Comment: @JayJona - `I need to divide 5 by the number of rows in this range that is two and save the nearest integer` - what is `range that is two` ? it is `10`, so need `5/10` ?

Comment: @JayJona - For `2022-11-09 14:14:00    3
2022-11-09 14:17:00    2` is `sum=5`, what is count?